# Cell couting formula

Tags: excel

I have a problem and I don't know how to solve it. Let's say in A1 I have "232" in A2 "321".
I want to have a formula in A3 which counts how many cells has "2"(in the example should return 2)
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use SUMPRODUCT

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(2,A1:A2)))
```

[image]

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your solution. It returns 0 for me. Am I doing something wrong? I am using Excel 2010.

Comment: I was thrown off by the `""` around the numbers, I thought they were entered that way in the cell.  with numbers we need to use sumproduct.

Comment: Why can't I just do `=COUNTIF(A1:A2,"*2*")`? That returns `0` for me.  If I make `A1` and `A2` `appleman` and `manapple`, I can get `2` from `=COUNTIF(A1:A2,"*apple*")`.  Do wildcards not work with numbers?

Comment: @BruceWayne started there, but it does not parse numbers.  It only works on text strings.  change the cells to text and it will work.

Comment: Hm, I tried making the cells the `Text` format, but it still returns `0`.  Oh well, learned something new! Cheers!

Comment: @BruceWayne if you put `'` in front of the numbers and turn them into text instead of just formatting them as text it will works.